# Mongo Map-Reduce To Mimic "count(distinct(...)) group" by in SQL

Tags: mongodb

I want to find how many unique products were sold per brand over a period of time. A single document looks like:

```
{
    brand_id: 1,
    product_id: 2,
    date: ISODate("2014-12-12")
}
```

In SQL this would be: `SELECT brand_id, count(distinct(product_id)) FROM orders WHERE date ... GROUP BY brand_id`;

I could not figure a way to do it through Mongo's aggregation framework (group and such). Here is the map-reduce I have now:

```
db.orders.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.brand_id, this.product_id);
    },
    function(key, values) {
        return values.filter(function (value, index, self) {return self.indexOf(value) === index;}).length;
    },
    {
        query: {date: {$gte: new Date('2014-11-20')}},
        out: "example"
    }
)
```

This looks all nice. However, I am running into an issue where the reduce function is not receiving all the "values" at once, but rather in batches of 101 elements. As such, any attempt to find unique values fails, and all I get is the number of unique elements in the LAST time the reduce function was called. I can't figure how I might make use of the "finalize" attribute here to get what I want.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I tried this on Mongo 2.4 and 2.6 just to make sure it's not a version issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I could not figure a way to do it through Mongo's aggregation framework (group and such)*

You could easily aggregate the result, instead of opting for an map-reduce solution:

- `Match` the records where the date is greater than equal to the
  specified date.
- `Group` based on the `brand_id` field.
- Use the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator to maintain a `products` list of unique
  `product_id` for each group.
- `Project` the `count` of the `products` array in each key.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"date":{$gte:new Date('2014-11-20')}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$brand_id","products":{$addToSet:"$product_id"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"brand_id":"$_id","distinct_prod":{$size:"$products"}}}
])
```

Coming to your map-reduce solution,

> *However, I am running into an issue where the reduce function is not receiving all the "values" at once, but rather in batches of 101
>   elements*

That is one way mongodb may invoke the reduce function for each group. From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function):

> MongoDB can invoke the reduce function more than once for the same
>   key. In this case, the previous output from the reduce function for
>   that key will become one of the input values to the next reduce
>   function invocation for that key.

You need to make some modification to you `map`,`reduce` functions and add a new `finalize` function:

- You need to remember that when `mongodb` invokes the `reduce`
  function for the same key more than once, the result of the previous
  invocation is passed as an input to the reduce function, along with
  the other values the next time the reduce function is invoked.
- First point, So you need to make sure the input to the reduce
  function and the return value from the reduce function are similarly
  constructed, so that the logic written inside the reduce function can
  accommodate processing its own returned value in its previous calls.
- Since we would not be able to retrieve the count of distinct values
  when called in batches, what we can do is, write a `reduce` function
  that accumulates the distinct `product_ids` for each key and write a
  `finalize` function that calculates the count of those unique values.

Code:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        // emitting the same structure returned by the reduce function.
        emit(this.brand_id, {"prod_id":[this.product_id]});
    },
    function(key, values) {
       // the return value would be a list of unique product_ids.
        var res = {"prod_id":[]};
        for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
        {
         for(var j=0;j<values[i].prod_id.length;j++){
            if(res.prod_id.indexOf(values[i].prod_id[j]) == -1){
                res.prod_id.push(values[i].prod_id[j]);
            }
        }}
        return res;
    },
    {
        query: {date: {$gte: new Date('2014-11-20')}},
        out: "example",
        finalize: function(key, reducedValue){
            // it returns just the count
            return reducedValue.prod_id.length;
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Trying to use $size aggregate function in the $project step of the pipeline requires Mongo 2.6